# Computer Doesn't recognise mouse clicks Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, mouse

I have a windows 7 PC. I was not using it for more than 6 months. Last day I had opened it and tried to do some works. But unfortunately my system doesn't recognize mouse clicks after few minutes. I am not able to open start menu, click on any buttons on the title bar etc. However I opened start menu from keyboard and when I clicked on the menu it get disappeared instead of opening the program.

I am connecting a USB mouse so I thought it was issue with mouse. So I changed couple of mouses and found that it is not related to the mouse. It works properly when I simply restarts the system. However the system will not recognize mouse click after few minutes.

My System Configurations:

Windows 7, Core I3 Processor, DH55PJ motherboard.

Did anyone face the same issue? Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: I've seen the same behavior on Windows 8.1 recently. Neither the touchpad nor the attached mouse works. Cursor moves, clicks not recognized.

Comment: the problem is with your mouse... i had the same problem with a Microsoft wireless mouse, and nothing worked when i click with the mouse... even the touch pad stoped responding. remove your mouse and turn your comp off and back on... then try your touch. all should work correctly... then plug your mouse and click on the bar and you will not be able to click on the desktop and vice-versa. i changed my mouse and everything is running fine again. :)

Comment: The problem is not with the mouse. I have mentioned in the question itself that I have checked with multiple mouses. But nothing worked on the PC how ever all of them worked on my laptop